# Spark Dataframe count function and many more functions throw IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

1) **Initially filtered RDD with null values.**

```
val rddWithOutNull2 = rddSlices.filter(x => x(0) != null)
```

2) **Then converted this RDD to RDD of Row**

3) **After converting RDD to Dataframe using Scala :**

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rddRow,schema)
df.printSchema()
```

**Output:**

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)


println(df.count())
```

**Output:**

```
Error : 
count : : 
[Stage 11:==================================>                       (3 + 2) / 5][error] o.a.s.e.Executor - Exception in task 4.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 16)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

- No other spark sql functions working on this spark dataframe.

Comment: Can you add some example input? And the code for step 2.

Comment: Data is like :  
df.show(5) :   
  
+-------------+  
|name|  
+-------------+    
|      abc|  
|      pqr|  
|      pqr|  
|      abc|  
|      pqr|  
+-------------+   
only showing top 5 rows

Comment: `rddSlices` might have empty array and access `x(0)` will cause `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: Add it to the question + all code necessary to reproduce the problem. Right now it's hard to say where the error is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the records from `rddSlices` is an empty list. Doing this `rddSlices.filter(! _.isEmpty).filter(x => x(0) != null)` would probably solve your problem.

Comment: rddSlices.filter(! _.isEmpty).filter(x => x(0) != null)
This solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: This worked without date in the RDD. But for date this does not solve the problem. Date is in the format of java.sql.Date.

Comment: Date is like `2017-06-30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with the comments, the problem seems to be in x(0). If there is an empty row, it will throw that `Exception`. One solution (depending on the type of the variable `x`) is to retrieve it with a headOption

```
val rddWithOutNull2 = rddSlices.filter(_.headOption.isDefined)
```