# Spark rdd correct date format in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, date-format

This is the date value I want to use when I convert RDD to Dataframe.

```
Sun Jul 31 10:21:53 PDT 2016
```

This schema "DataTypes.DateType" throws an error.

```
java.util.Date is not a valid external type for schema of date
```

So I want to prepare RDD in advance in such a way that above schema can work.
How can I correct the date format to work in conversion to dataframe?

```
//Schema for data frame
val schema =
                StructType(
                    StructField("lotStartDate", DateType, false) ::
                    StructField("pm", StringType, false) ::
                    StructField("wc", LongType, false) ::
                    StructField("ri", StringType, false) :: Nil)

// rowrdd : [Sun Jul 31 10:21:53 PDT 2016,"PM",11,"ABC"]
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rddRow,schema)
```

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to convert the RDD into a DataFrame? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful (code that creates a sample RDD, converts it to DF, and throws the error you reported).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark's `DateType` can be encoded from `java.sql.Date`, so you should convert your input RDD to use that type, e.g.:

```
val inputRdd: RDD[(Int, java.util.Date)] = ??? // however it's created

// convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date:
val fixedRdd = inputRdd.map {
  case (id, date) => (id, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime))
}

// now you can convert to DataFrame given your schema:
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("id", IntegerType) :: 
  StructField("date", DateType) :: 
  Nil
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  fixedRdd.map(record => Row.fromSeq(record.productIterator.toSeq)),
  schema
)

// or, even easier - let Spark figure out the schema:
val df2 = fixedRdd.toDF("id", "date")

// both will evaluate to the same schema, in this case
```

Comment: Worked!!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Error` occurs while converting RDD to Dataframe in both ways.
I am also cleaning RDD like
`val rddFinal = rddFlat.filter(x => (x._1 != null && x._1.isInstanceOf[Date] && x._2 != null && x._3 != null && x._4 != null && x._2.length>0 && x._4.length>0))`
Refer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416695/spark-dataframe-count-function-and-many-more-functions-throw-indexoutofboundsexc]
This worked without date in the RDD. But for date this does not solve the problem.