# Convert RDD[List[AnyRef]] to RDD[List[String, Date, String, String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to set return type of RDD. But it is RDD[List[AnyRef]].
So I am not able to specify anything directly.
Like,

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.filter(! _.isEmpty).filter(x => x(0) != null)
```

This returns RDD[List[String, Date, String, String]] type of RDD but it was RDD[List[AnyRef]].

**EDIT**

```
rdd1:
List(Sun Jul 31 10:21:53 PDT 2016, pm1, 11, ri1)
List(Mon Aug 01 12:57:09 PDT 2016, pm3, 5, ri1)
List(Mon Aug 01 01:11:16 PDT 2016, pm1, 1, ri2)
```

This rdd1 is RDD[List[AnyRef]] type.

Now I want rdd2 in this type:

```
RDD[List[Date, String, Long, String]]
```

The reason is that I am facing issues with date while converting RDD to Data Frame using schema. To deal with that firstly I have to fix the RDD type.
That problem's solution is :
[Spark rdd correct date format in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469234/spark-rdd-correct-date-format-in-scala)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the full input and output you need

Comment: Updated question!! Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant `List[(Date, String, Long, String)]`. `List[Date, String, Long, String]` is not a valid type (not with the usual definition of `List`). What's the problem with casting operator `asInstanceOf` or pattern-matching-filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example which leads to the same problem (I omitted `Date`, replaced it by `String`, that's not the point):

```
val myRdd = sc.makeRDD(List(
  List[AnyRef]("date 1", "blah2", (11: java.lang.Integer), "baz1"),
  List[AnyRef]("date 2", "blah3", (5: java.lang.Integer),  "baz2"),
  List[AnyRef]("date 3", "blah4", (1: java.lang.Integer),  "baz3") 
))

// myRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[AnyRef]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0]
```

Here is how you can recover the types:

```
val unmessTypes = myRdd.map{
  case List(a: String, b: String, c: java.lang.Integer, d: String) => (a, b, (c: Int), d)
}

// unmessTypes: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1]
```

You simply apply a partial function that matches lists of length 4 with elements of specified types, and constructs the tuples of expected type out of it. If your RDD indeed contains only lists of length 4 with the expected types, the partial function will never fail.

Comment: Here I am converting my list of rdd to flat list, so 
`List(Tue Sep 13 02:44:31 PDT 2016, pm, 12, ri)` is converted to 
`Tue Sep 13 02:44:31 PDT 2016`, Now as per above description, I can use partial function with bunch of 4 and make it like `(Tue Sep 13 02:44:31 PDT 2016, pm, 12, ri)`? But I am not able to figure how to apply the partial function.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to "figure out"? Take the last code snippet as-is, replace the types by whatever you want (in your case: `a: Date, b: String, c: Integer, d: String`), build a tuple of the right type from the four values. And after that, try not to lose any types. I don't quite understand how this untyped data ended up in RDD in the first place.

Comment: Worked!!
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your [Spark rdd correct date format in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469234/spark-rdd-correct-date-format-in-scala), it seems that you are having issue in converting your rdd to dataframe. [Tzach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48469623/5880706) has already answered it correctly to convert the `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` and that should solve your issue.

First of all a `List` cannot have separate *dataType* for each element in the list as we do have for `Tuples`. `List` have only one *dataType* and if mixed *dataTypes* are used then the *dataType* of the list is represented as `Any` or `AnyRef`.

I guess you must have created data as below

```
val list = List(
  List[AnyRef](new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Sun Jul 31 10:21:53 PDT 2016"), "pm1", 11L: java.lang.Long,"ri1"),
  List[AnyRef](new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Mon Aug 01 12:57:09 PDT 2016"), "pm3", 5L: java.lang.Long, "ri1"),
  List[AnyRef](new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Mon Aug 01 01:11:16 PDT 2016"), "pm1", 1L: java.lang.Long, "ri2")
)

val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list)
```

which would give

```
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[AnyRef]]
```

but in fact its real *datatypes* are `[java.util.Date, String, java.lang.Long, String]`

And looking at your other question you must be having problem converting the `rdd` to `dataframe` having following `schema`

```
val schema =
  StructType(
    StructField("lotStartDate", DateType, false) ::
      StructField("pm", StringType, false) ::
      StructField("wc", LongType, false) ::
      StructField("ri", StringType, false) :: Nil)
```

What you can do is utilize `java.sql.Date` api as answered in your other question and then create `dataframe` as

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list).map(lis => Row.fromSeq(new java.sql.Date((lis.head.asInstanceOf[java.util.Date]).getTime)::lis.tail))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1,schema)
```

which should give you

```
+------------+---+---+---+
|lotStartDate|pm |wc |ri |
+------------+---+---+---+
|2016-07-31  |pm1|11 |ri1|
|2016-08-02  |pm3|5  |ri1|
|2016-08-01  |pm1|1  |ri2|
+------------+---+---+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful